# How to get term alias in twig templates

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have created a block to show the sibling terms of the term being viewed. In the twig template I am looping through the terms to display the names linked to their respective pages.

Now I unable to figure out how to get path alias.

Can any one of you please guide me how to get the path alias of a term?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

A bit late, but just figured this one out in case it helps someone else:

```
{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. It is often nice to enclose code in code formatting. This can be done by indenting multi-line code with 4 or so spaces, or enclosing a single line with backticks.